# In inline asm within C, on x86/x86-64, is the value of the direction flag guaranteed to be cld?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, eflags

In inline asm within C, on x86/x86-64, is the value of the direction flag guaranteed to be cld always or do I have to set the state to cld every time I need it? And if I execute a cld do I have to preserve the previous state for any caller of the current routine who might have the state currently set to direction=downwards when they called me?

Comment: I know that under [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=msvc-170#x64-register-usage): *On function exit and on function entry to C Runtime Library calls and Windows system calls, the direction flag in the CPU flags register is expected to be cleared.*

Comment: Most (if not all) ABIs followed by compilers require D=0 for every function call and return. So if you change it to 1 you have to change it back and if you need it to be 0, you can rely on that.  This is defined by the compiler and the ABI it supports, not the C language or the hardware architecture, so you should check the compiler you're using.

Comment: @prl: The ABI is separate from inline-asm guarantees.  I think it's unlikely that GCC or clang ever emit `std` inside functions, though, so in this case the DF state will always match the ABI.  (All of which require DF=0 on call/ret as you say.)

Comment: Many thanks to all. I may as well omit the cld’s in my D (GDC and LDC) wrapped library routines.

Comment: For what it's worth, `grep -w std` in `gcc/config/i386` doesn't turn up anything except `std::swap` and the like.

Comment: Thank-you Nate, that was a good idea!

Comment: @Peter, yes, I was making that assumption, and neglected to say it explicitly.